# How should I do this in CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

I am currently creating a dropshadow effect using PHP to send html to the clients computer, in other words, i display a 1px shadow image along the height and width of the image.

I want to do this with CSS! but how?

The shadow images for the left side are 4x1 px, and bottom are 1x4 px. Then I have 3 images for the three corners, top-left, left-bottom, right-bottom which are 4x4 px.

If I could stretch a 1px image along a side or tile it, then it would work, but I dont know how to stretch or tile it to the main images height...

Any help would be very appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/category/C5/

CSS3 Box Shadows ("box-shadow" property).

Comment: But go through this link and find all the examples It able to work in all browsers i have checked in IE6 also

Comment: FF3.5, Safari 3.1+, and Google Chrome, IE has long supported simple drop shadows via its pripoertary "Drop Shadow" filter